# C# WinForm application supporting Google Checkout?

Tags: c#, google-checkout

I am working on a project where entire application is C# WinForm desktop application. Now our client want to support an action on a form which results in user being charged via his/her Google checkout account. I am wondering if I can provide a checkout interface similar to web browser using windows form or not. If so, How?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the native winforms WebBrowser control?

The WebBrowser control lets you host Web pages and other browser-enabled documents in your Windows Forms applications. You can use the WebBrowser control, for example, to provide integrated HTML-based user assistance or Web browsing capabilities in your application. Additionally, you can use the WebBrowser control to add your existing Web-based controls to your Windows Forms client applications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx